# Adjective for something that is medium-lived

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective that can be used to describe something that is somewhere between *ephemeral*, *transient* or *temporary* and *persistent*, *permanent* or *continual* in length of time. That is, I want to give the impression that something can last for a while (not fleeting), but that can change at any time and can or will have an ending. Thus even *persistent* sounds too *permanent* for what I'm looking for.

Some ideas I've come across so far that seem too long / too permanent:  *preserved*, *protracted*, *prolonged*, *lasting*, *long-lived* (maybe *medium-lived*?), *durable*. And some that I think are potential candidates: *retained*, *sustained*, *maintained*, *stable*, *durational*. My current favorite is *durational*, which seems to give the right feel. On the other hand, it feels awkward to me when I use it in a sentence. I'd love to hear other suggestions or recommendations.  Also, please let me know if you agree or disagree with my interpretation of the choices mentioned here or in the comments.

I'm looking to contrast a temporary selection (like a user doing a mouseover or hover to see a tooltip) with a durational selection that implies the user has chosen some things to look at for a time, but may modify that selection at any time as they desire.

So which of these sound like something that will last a while, but you're free to modify or delete or undo whenever you like:

- a retained selection
- a sustained selection
- a maintained selection
- a stable selection
- a durational selection
- an impermanent selection
- a semi-permanent selection
- an epochal selection (ok that **does** sound long!)

Comment: How about he simple, direct, *impermanent*?

Comment: semi-permanent. Also, did a thesaurus say anything?

Comment: I think _impermanent_ implies too short a duration and would therefore not contrast well with _temporary_, looking at synonyms on dictionary.com I see _fleeting_, _temporary_, _ephemeral_, _evanescent_. But please let me know if you don't agree with this implication.

Comment: _semi-permanent_ feels closer, more in-between than _impermanent_.  The thesaurus is what I used to get the list above.

Comment: Is longevity too ... long? (PS: I think @FumbleFingers made a mistake flagging this. The two questions are very different.)

Comment: The dupe isn't a dupe. The answers there have nothing to do with longevity: they deal in *space* (distance), not *time*. Voting to re-open.

Comment: The adjective for _longevity_ is... _longevous_?  So I'm realizing there are a lot of great nouns that convey a period of time that isn't too short or isn't too long.  So maybe I can start from there and convert to adjectives... _era_, _interval_, _period_ (though _periodic_ implies repetition), _epoch_...  Hmmm, maybe _epochal_.

Comment: *Epochal* conveys a looooooong time indeed. But not eternal, I'll grant.

Comment: Sustained is too long and temporary is too short? This is tricky. Neither has to mean particularly long or short.

Comment: I agree that _sustained_ is close to what I'm looking for, I'll edit my question to show which ones I think are good candidates vs what I've dismissed.  And to show that I'm looking for feedback to make sure I'm getting a good feel for how others will interpret it.

Comment: I vote (as answers aren't allowed) for "a sustained selection". Alternative vote for "a maintained selection".

Comment: How many selections can there be?  Why not just use "*current selection*" which implies that it is the most recent selection and will hang around until something new is selected?

Comment: _Current selection_ could work, but I'm trying to avoid ambiguity here: when item(s) are currently selected (or a set of items is in the sustained selection), and the user then hovers over an item to temporarily select that item, the most current thing is now the temporary selection; however, the sustained selection should not be changed. But if context can make this clear, perhaps _current selection_ will work. Ok, @Avon, I think this shows my trouble with _sustained_; I also need an adverb form of the word. Can I say "sustainedly selected items" or "these items were sustainedly selected"?

Comment: If it's still voting for ones you have eliminated then I vote "persistent" or "continual". The only word I haven't seen suggested that might work is "lingering"

Comment: The reason I closevoted is because it seems to me both questions turn on the same issue, which I think has been asked in before respect of various other "quantifiable attributes". This time it's *lifespan, longevity*, rather than *distance*, but it would be the same with *What's a word for medium/average/normal **height, weight, size, age, speed, difficulty, educational attainment,** etc.?* There are no "derived forms" for such attributes, so it just looks like writing advice to me.

Comment: Taking a somewhat different approach to this, have you considered using a term like **basket** to cover your selection? It's a metaphor used by a number of online shopping-related sites, typically for a selection that can change at any time and can or will have an ending. (If your context is not shopping-related, a similar noun may still be suitable.)

Answer (score 1):

How about "semiperennial"like the plant snap dragon(selected from wordsmith.com) which acts like perennial in mild winter and dies completely in hard winter? Semidurable may do as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't recommend 'durational'. It's not used outside of the performance art context.  Of the rest, 'retained' sounds closest, but I would probably say "working selection" or "working sample" or "saved selection", "reserved" or even just 'selected'.  Or perhaps the word from your description "chosen" is as good as any.  An illustrative sentence would help.

Answer (score 0):

*[appologies for this non answer answer, but it wouldn't fit in a comment, and I thought it might still be relevant]*

This sounds a lot like you're trying to describe a computer UX affordance.

My advice is to stop trying to map a complex abstract into plain English. What'll likely happen is that you'll keep stretching until you find something you're satisfied with, but your audience won't have gone through the same process, and so will not come to the same conclusion.

To illustrate, you've gotten caught up thinking that epoch means a long time, when it actually just means a distinct time. In colloquial computer terms, for instance, the Unix epoch is the period of time from the 1st of January 1970 until the end of time. It is so called because the Unix system standard for storing a time value is in seconds since that moment. If you tried to use that word here, you might end up giving the false impression that the selection was entirely permanent. Alternatively, you can look at the same usage as being the same as the usage of epoch in physics, where it only denotes a single moment in time. In that case the colloquial computer speaker might consider the Unix epoch to be that one moment in 1970. That would instead make the meaning of your epochal selection a snapshot of a selection perhaps?

There are similar problems with the rest of the terms too. Stability, for instance, in computer algorithms usually refers to resistance against shuffling order. A stable sort is one in which elements with the same sort order will remain in the same order relative to each other after the sort. I might read "stable selection" as a selection in which the order I chose the items is preserved.

If you have a selection list, call it that. If you support temporary selection on top of that, call it that. Everything else just isn't selected, right? If you support even more selection modes, then it's probably worth naming the individual selection collections something else entirely: the duration of the selection is now a saturated concept.

Granted, this is tricky stuff. Best of luck navigating the wild linguistic frontier of software documentation!